# firebase user.uid returns null although user is returned corrently

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I am using the firebase sdk for flutter to sign up users. The firebase function `signInWithEmailAndPassword` returns me a userCredential. It contains a user object in it.

```
userCredential = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
  email: email,
  password: password,
);

final user = userCredential.user;
if (user != null) {
  print(user);                                //  1
  print(user.uid);                            //  2
}

await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .doc(userCredential.user!.uid)            //  3
    .set({
  'username': username,
  'email': email,
});
```

The above script returned a correct user object:

> flutter: User(displayName: null, email: a3@gmail.com, emailVerified: false, isAnonymous: false, metadata: UserMetadata(creationTime: 2023-03-21 03:52:37.635Z, lastSignInTime: 2023-03-21 03:52:37.635Z), phoneNumber: null, photoURL: null, providerData, [UserInfo(displayName: null, email: a3@gmail.com, phoneNumber: null, photoURL: null, providerId: password, uid: a3@gmail.com)], refreshToken: , tenantId: null, uid: d3wI96PxFKSHGiXb8CIVlIJtC0r2)

however, on line 2, the getter uid returned me a null, and caused error on line 3.

I am expecting uid getter returns me a String so that I can use it to store user's information on firestore.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this to get the userId

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
```

Comment: Thanks but I tried it and it still does not work